# WTForms, radiofields with additional 'labels'

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I have a dynamically generated RadioField in a form that I render in a template

```
class F(Form):
    pass

F.selection = RadioField(
    'selection',
    choices=options,
    validators=[
        DataRequired()
    ]
)
```

'options' is a an array of tuples that is generated, this works fine. It prints the options when I have this in my template

```
{% for subfield in form.selection %}
<p>
<tr>
    <td>{{ subfield }}</td>
    <td>{{ subfield.label }}</td>
</tr>
</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Issue that I am facing right now is that this gives me a set of radio buttons with a text next to it. In this case the 'title' of what I want people to chose between.

But I want to have additional info there, eg. a description, size, image maybe, etc.

I have currently tried making a list of tuples with this extra info and passing it to the template. I can access the extra info there but I can't figure out how to iterate over both sets of data at the same time

```
{% for item in data %}
<p>
    {{ item[0] }}
    {{ item[1] }}
    {{ item[2] }}
</p>
{% endfor %}
```

what I want is to put this in one for loop so I can make pretty 'enhanced' options. Now I would use zip, but I can't do that in Jinja2 ( I think) and I can't zip it beforehand because the radiofield choices argument won't take that.

so any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

This will work, on back-end/Python side use:

```
form = TestRadio()
form.radio.choices = [('one', '1'), ('two', '2')]
extra_stuff = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f')]
```

`TestRadio` inherits from a flask-wtf `Form`, as below:

```
class TestRadio(Form):
    radio = RadioField()
```

Assuming `extra_stuff` has the same length as number of choices, then in jinja2:

```
<form>
    <table>
    {% for subfield in form.radio %}
    <tr>  
        <td> {{ form.csrf_token }} </td>
        <td> {{ subfield }} </td>
        {% for item in extra_stuff[loop.index0] %}
          <td> {{ item }} </td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
</form>
```

In summary set *choices* on the Python side, within a view function. The trick is this `loop` variable I used. It tracks the index of the outer level for loop. (http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/tricks/#accessing-the-parent-loop)

Regarding adding images:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#static-files

Comment: Ok I might be missing something here - I am fairly new to using WTForms and jinja - but if you do what you do here in block #1 you create several RadioFields. Then in block #2 you create several options for each RadioField. But I only need one RadioField with one choices array, it's just that every element in that choices array needs to be associated with extra data. Not the RadioField itself. maybe I was being unclear there.

Comment: Then it's easier if I understand correctly. Just use something like the `radio.choices` in the above and feed it the zipped data.

Comment: Ah, but that doesn't work as far as I've tried. Choices only accepts stuff like this choices = [('choice_1', 'something'),('choice_2','something_else')]

Basically if I make it an array of bigger tuples you get this: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

I have also tried to make the second part in the tuple another list, but it only accepts strings.

Comment: @Thustra Just out of curiosity, how did this turn out for you?

Comment: Hi, I'll just post a link the the reddit thread where I managed to fix it with some help

https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/3z0w8y/need_some_help_with_form_workflow/

Comment: This answer works for me. The solution in the Reddit post looks interesting, too. Could you post that as another answer?